# Spotlight doesn't show Finder

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

I typed "Finder" in Spotlight. Finder isn't shown. Why?
I use Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

[image]

On Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) typing "Finder" in Spotlight does display the finder app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Finder is located inside /System/Library. (Specifically, at /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app.) Everything inside any of the Library folders is considered a "system file", and not normally visible.

Interestingly, Yosemite seems to have made an exception for /System/Library/CoreServices, treating it more like an applications folder than a library folder. Spotlight will show Finder in Yosemite.

In a Finder search window (which is basically Spotlight with more focus on finding files but little or none on finding non-files), you need to add a `[System files][are included]` search term to see system files. If you don't see `System files` as an option in that first menu, select "Other..." and find "System files". (Note that you can search for it!) For future convenience, put a checkmark on it to add it to the menu.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish? Finder.app is hidden. If you wish to quickly open finder, command-tab is easy.

If that's your goal, some of these suggestions may be helpful. Personally I use finder windows accessed via command-tab. I dragged my Downloads directory into the sidebar (it should be there already). So: command-tab to finder, click Downloads in the sidebar and viola. Alternatively, you could drag the downloads folder to the dock (it should be there already). Or, swipe 4 fingers down to reveal desktop (an option in system preferences -> trackpad), then click desktop to select finder.

In Automator you could build a workflow and save it as a service. In Automator use open finder and save as a service. This will put it in your Library to be available across applications. Then enable a quick key assigning a keyboard shortcut in system preferences -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> services.

Comment: Thanks. I was surprised as on Yosemite typing "Finder" does display the finder app.

Comment: cheers. that is an interesting change, perhaps another can say why...